# How to get the main domain string using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have just started using regular expression and i landed up in a problem. So it would be really nice if someone can help me out with it.

The problem is, in case I have a url as given below;

```
$url = http://www.blog.domain.com/page/category=?
```

and want only the **domain**, how can i get it using regular expression in javascript.

thank you

Comment: Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too, but most restrictive and shorter:

```
var url = "http://www.blog.domain.com/page/category"
var result = url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(.+\.)*(([a-z0-9-]*)\.[a-z]{2,6})(\/.+)$/i,"$4")
```

If you want "domain.com" and not only "domain", use **$3** instead of **$4**.

**Explaination step by step:**

- A correct domain syntax: letters,numbers and "-" `/([a-z0-9-]*)/i`
- Domain extension (2-6 chars): `/(([a-z0-9-]*)\.[a-z]{2,6})/i`
- Subdomains: `/(.+\.)*(([a-z0-9-]*)\.[a-z]{2,6})/i`
- An url start with http and maybe http**s**: `/^https?:\/\/(.+\.)*(([a-z0-9-]*)\.[a-z]{2,6})/i`
- You can put or not http when you type an url: `/^(https?:\/\/)?(.+\.)*(([a-z0-9-]*)\.[a-z]{2,6})/i`
- Then what is after /: `/^(https?:\/\/)?(.+\.)*(([a-z0-9-]*)\.[a-z]{2,6})(\/.+)$/i`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 var url = "http://www.blog.domain.com/page/category=?";
 var match = url .match(/(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)\//);
 console.log(match[match.length-1]);
```

Comment: but what if i have a url like **http://www.blog.domain.com/page/category=?product.asp**. In this case i would be getting **product** and not **domain**

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regex for this:

use [hostname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.hostname):

> The URLUtils.hostname property is a DOMString containing the domain of
>   the URL.

```
var x = new URL("http://www.blog.domain.com/page/category=?").hostname;
console.log(x);
```

as pointed by vishwanath, URL faces compatibilty issues with IE<10 so for those cases, regex will be needed.

use this :

```
var str = "http://www.blog.domain.com/page/category=?";
var res = str.match(/[^.]*.(com|net|org|info|coop|int|co\.uk|org\.uk|ac\.uk|uk)/g);
console.log(res);

=> domain.com
```

the list in the regex can be expanded further depending upon your need.
a list of TLDs can be found [here](https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat)

Comment: Also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I tried this but it gave me **www.blog.domain.com** but whereas i need only **domain** out of it.

Comment: @AmandaWalker The `domain` part by itself is not a domain name.

Comment: then which part is the domain ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using the following RegEx: `/.*\.(.+)\.[com|org|gov]/`

You can add all of the supported domain extensions in this regex.

[RegEx101 Explanation](https://www.regex101.com/r/oL7sQ8/2)

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var url = "http://www.blog.domain.gov/page/category=?";

var regEx = /.*\.(.+)\.[com|org|gov]/;

alert(url.match(regEx)[1]);
```

Comment: bro all urls do not end in `.com`